# Approximately how much water does Earth acquire/lose annually from extra-terrestrial sources?

Tags: water, atmosphere

- The approximate volume of water on Earth is [1.338 Billion cu.km](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water#cite_note-b1-5)
- Earth regularly intercepts a number of space objects as meteors
- During the course of their descent through the atmosphere some burn totally to ash
- Larger bodies may make it through the atmosphere burning off a part of their content which may remain part of the atmosphere, or make it to the surface.

  1. Does a meteor (subject to it's composition) add to, or deduct from the water volume on Earth?
  2. What is the approximate volume of water acquired/lost annually to such extra-terrestrial bodies by Earth?

Comment: This fits rather on Physics than on Space Exploration, perhaps.

Comment: Hydrogen is lost naturally, and [so is oxygen](http://www.irf.se/Topical/Press/?dbfile=Utfl%F6det%20av%20syre%20fr%E5n%20jordens%20atmosf%E4r%20ingenting%20att%20oroa%20sig%20%F6ver&dbsec=P2) (but only 20 ton per day, which is no problem).

Comment: The ET element made me think the question is be better suited here but I dread you may be right ..

Comment: According to Emily Pope (University of Copenhagen): _["Less than ¼ of its water budget over the last roughly 4 billion years."](http://news.ku.dk/all_news/2012/2012.3/new-water-budget-on-planet-earth/)_, but I'm not entirely sure this question is on-topic here. There are of course other sources and studies, but I'd believe those we have actual evidence here on the good old Earth first, personally. ;)

Comment: Well, note by *perhaps*.  I'm not sure how much space science is on-topic on space exploration.

Comment: It is a question, which is, in one way or another, investigated with sounding rockets, experiments on the ISS and satellites. It is definitely atmospheric physics, but the atmosphere 'interacts' with space, so - **it does fit in here**, although not exclusively. (This would be a beautiful question for a geoscience.SE ...)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the existence of geoscience SE... Would somebody perform migration please?